# I have a question about VoltDB.(foreign key constraint)

Tags: database, voltdb

I am studying VoltDB.

Why is there no foreign key constraint in VoltDB??

Is there a technical reason ??

Comment: Check this: https://www.quora.com/Why-dont-NewSQL-databases-enforce-foreign-key-integrity So the main reason is simple support of scaling up.